# Why this code don't regonize lista as a list?

Tags: python, list, typeerror

So I'm learning python and I tried to make a code to generate a list but when I try to run the code a error saying that the list is of type function and I don't understand why here is the code:

```
def criarlista():
  lista = []
  for x in range(10):
    lista[x] = int(secrets.randbelow(100000) + 1)
  return lista

lista = []
lista = criarlista
size = len(lista)
```

Comment: You didn't _call_ the function.

Comment: it's not a list, it's a function

Comment: btw, when you get round to fixing your `TypeError`, you will end up with an `IndexError`.

Answer (score 1):

Because in that example `lista` is getting reassigned to `criarlista` which is **not** the same as `criarlsita()`; the latter is an actual call to the function. Instead you need to do: `lista = criarlista()`

Comment: ok this worked now another error saying : "IndexError: list assignment index out of range" can you help again, is the same code with the only alteration with your suggestion.

Comment: use append to add an item to the list

Comment: @Adriel you're assigning to indexes of the list that do not exist. Change the inside of the loop to be: `lista.append(int(secrets.randbelow(100000) + 1))`

Comment: ok thanks!! that worked but is anyway to work with the index values?

Comment: Those indexes need to be initialized before you can index into them. `lista = [x for x in range(10)]`